# resource listing

Tags: image, file, resources, wicket, directory-listing

I writing wicket webapp. I want to:

1. list all resources - videoPreview in the folder
2. preview it
3. add link to show in main preview panel.

I read a lot and look examples about resources, but seems like can't understand smthg. I write such funny code:

```
        RepeatingView rv = new RepeatingView("showVideo");
    add(rv);
    File vidPrevDir = (new File("data/catalog/"+product+"/videoPreview"));
    File[] list = vidPrevDir.listFiles();

    for (File file : list) {
        final String previewFile = file.getName();
        AjaxLink link = new AjaxLink(rv.newChildId()){              
            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                container.name="iframe";
                container.attrs.clear();
                container.attrs.put("class", "viewPanel");
                container.attrs.put("allowfullscreen", "yes");
                container.attrs.put("src", "http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+previewFile.substring(previewFile.indexOf("___"), previewFile.length()-4));
                target.add(container);                  
            }

        };
        rv.add(link);
        link.add(new Image("videoPreview", product+"/videoPreview/"+file.getName()));
    }
```

In application i call
getResourceSettings().addResourceFolder("data");

It's work, but i feel bad when i see that. So my question is how to make such things in wicket? Maybe there is resource listing or java.io.File->wicket.Image converter ?

Comment: Which part of the code are you concerned about?

Comment: First i list files in directory and then i make File->construct filename->Image conversion. So the path is constructed twice. I think i must get Image by File/URL, which already exist or i must list resources directly. The last is preferable, because i can move resources. But don't find way to list resources in some path.

Answer (score 0):

I only found built-in method:

ServletContext context = WicketApplication.get().getServletContext();
Set productList = context.getResourcePaths("/catalog");

It list filenames, not resources, but it is preferable approach, then i use in question.